# Sync files with permissions from linux to windows?

Tags: linux, filesystems, chmod

Is it possible to sync files from a linux machine with a given permission set (for instance, 700) to a windows machine (having a ntfs partition) and still retain linux permissions? I know that copying any file from linux to windows will set permissions to 777.

I need to keep some files in sync but I also need to retain the permissions. If not possible, I need an alternative solution to achieve this.

Comment: maybe you can use getfacl before sync and setfacl after on linux system ? also check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/86959/any-way-of-maintaining-permissions-when-using-ntfs-mounted-drive-in-ubuntu

Comment: `0700` *for whom*? How do you plan to map Linux and Windows users and groups?

Comment: @AlexP for me, as the current user. As for the map between Linux and Windows, I don't know if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can get close with rsync + you'll have to manually install rsync using [Cygwin Tools](https://www.cygwin.com/) + then make sure you only use simple permissions. ACLs + XATTRs will not transfer from Linux to Windows, as there's no matching permissions on Windows.

[Win 10 Rsync Installation Instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GwEcijAcW0) provides some good assistance + also references to other useful, related resources.

I wish Microsoft would just ship Rsync on all machines... well... I also wish they based off a Linux Kernel, so the bulk of useful public code could be run on their platform too.